# Play 2 media files synchronously with one set of controls for both

Tags: audio, video, media, media-player

I have 2 media files:

- Video+(2x)audio (Movie).
- Audio (Commentary).

Commentary audio track starts with an offset before the movie starts.*

I need to be able to(simultaneously):

- See the video track of the first file.
- Hear one of the the audio tracks of the first file.
- Hear the audio tracks of the second file.
- Play/Pause, FFW/RWD (or seek on the progress bar) all of the video/audio tracks simultaneously.
- Set volume balance between the two playing audio tracks.
- *Set an offset for the auxiliary audio track (commentary).

I need not to mux/resample or in any way edit the source media files as this would disable dynamic volume balance control (and possibly deteriorate quality).

How can I achieve this?

Already tried to no avail:

- Multiple instances of players with global keys. VLC and MPC-HC tested.
  Resulted in one of the instances possessively claiming the shortcut.
- Bino.
  Just doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Nuendo will do this, but do look into it further...

Comment: @Dave, that would be equivalent to employing any video editor as a player. It is an idea to keep in mind.

Comment: Must be free software?

Comment: @cdlvcdlv, not necessarily.